# jQuery and ajax response function

Tags: jquery, function, response

I have these functions. My objective is separate the load function to the rest of the script because i want to customize the loading message

```
function loadContent(url)
{
    $('body').html('Loading');
    content = load(url);
    $('body').html(content);
}

function load(url)
{

    var result = null;
    var scriptUrl = url;
    $.ajax({
        url: scriptUrl,
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'html',
        async: false,
        success: function(data) {
            result = data;
        } 
    });
    return result;
}
```

Now, I call the loadContent function:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    loadContent('index.php');    
});
```

The problem is in this line:

```
content = load(url);
```

because the function load() override the loading message.

How can I solve this?
Thanks guys!

Comment: *"because the function load() override the loading message"*, not quite sure what that means. What happens and what do you expect to happen? Why are you using a synchronous request anyway?

Answer (score 1):

As you ajax success need some time to make retrieve data from server, so your return will always null i.e undefined. So you need to loadContent within ajax success function.

```
function beforeLoad(){
   $('body').html('Loading');
}

function loadContent(data)
{
    $('body').html(data);
}

function load(url)
{
    var result = null;
    var scriptUrl = url;
    $.ajax({
        url: scriptUrl,
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'html',
        async: false,
        success: function(data) {
            result = data;
            loadContent(result);

            // You can also set result as html without calling a loadContent

            $('body').html(data);
        } 
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(e) {
    beforeLoad();
    load('index.php');    
});
```

Comment: There is no reason for this request to be synchronous anymore, since you are (rightly) no longer attempting to return anything

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function load(url)
{
    return $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'html',
        async: false
    }).responseText;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't try and use the data until the ajax event has returned successfully. Try this and see if it helps.

```
function loadContent (url) {
    var content = {};
    $('body').ajaxStart(function() {
        $(this).html('Loading');
    }).ajaxSuccess(function() {
        $(this).html(content.key);
    }).ajaxError(function() {
        $(this).html('Error');
    });

    load(url, content);
}

function load(url, content)
{
    var scriptUrl = url;
    $.ajax({
        url: scriptUrl,
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(data) {
            content['key'] = data;
        } 
    });
}
```